# PHP to get real client info IP or host name

Tags: php, server

I need to get real local ipaddress so that I can restrict only the specific computer in the organization can access web system.
I understand that $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will return the internet client IP but I really need to get the local ip address that has been assigned. Or is there any a way to determine the specific source?

Comment: If the website is hosted in the internal network - the `REMOTE_ADDR` will have the internal ip. Otherwise you can't know it (and you should not rely on it).

Comment: Usually you can't get the LAN address. The WAN is what is broadcast.

Comment: This is not possible with PHP